# Bash Script for Multiple Selections and Command Input

Tags: linux, bash, select, rar

I've created a bash script for selecting files/folders to insert into a RAR command:

```
#!/bin/bash

prompt="Please select a file:"
options=( $(find -maxdepth 1 -print0 | xargs -0) )

PS3="$prompt "
select opt in "${options[@]}" "Quit" ; do 
if (( REPLY == 1 + ${#options[@]} )) ; then
    exit

elif (( REPLY > 0 && REPLY <= ${#options[@]} )) ; then
   echo  "You picked $opt which is folder $REPLY"
    echo -e "What do you want to name your archive?"
    read archivename
    rar a $archivename.rar $opt
    break

else
    echo "Invalid option. Try another one."
fi
done
```

So this creates a list of all the files/folders where ever I'm running the script, then puts my selection into a "RAR" command to rar the selected files or folders.

I would like to be able to run the script and select multiple files and folders for input in to the rar command. Those files could be for sequential commands or the same command ... IE:

```
rar a $archivename.rar $opt1 $opt2 $opt3 $opt4
```

OR

```
rar a $archivename.rar $opt
rar a $archivename1.rar $opt1
rar a $archivename2.rar $opt2
```

With the second example showing the commands that would be run sequentially.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to be able to run the script and select multiple files
>   and folders for input in to the rar command.

You could use a `dialog` checklist for that. Example (given that `${options[@]}` contains the list of all the files/folders to select from):

```
prompt="Please select files:"
set -- "${options[@]/#/\"}"; set -- "${@/%/\" \"\" \"\"}"
read -a opt < <(eval dialog --checklist '"$prompt"' 0 0 0 $@ 2>&1 >/dev/tty)
[ "$opt" ] || exit
eval opt=(${opt[@]})    # parse the quotes
```

The `set` commands put quotes around the filenames so that it also works with names containing spaces. The selected names are put in `${opt[@]}`. You can then

```
rar a $archivename.rar "${opt[@]}"
```

or

```
rar a $archivename.rar "${opt[0]}"
rar a $archivename.rar "${opt[1]}"
rar a $archivename.rar "${opt[2]}"
```